# JHipster Rename Primary key and add changeset to json

Tags: java, liquibase, jhipster

Today i started looking at `JHipster` and have few question.

anyone knows how to rename id column name ? and i would like to add some change in existing `json` file so it can alter the database and create the Domain as per that , is there any document which talks about change the existing domain/database in `JHipster` (with or without using change set)?

as by default JHipster generated primary key column name as id but i want column name as product_id,sale_id. How to do this while generate entity?

is there any easy way to generate all the entity json file from my existing database, as some tool can do this for hibernate (database table to hbm file)?

Comment: for database reverse engineering, check out Spring Roo - http://projects.spring.io/spring-roo/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't easily change the way primary keys are generated by JHipster, it would require you to customize the entity generator, which basically means writing a [JHipster module](https://jhipster.github.io/modules/creating-a-module/) or worse forking JHipster project.

There is currently no way to reverse engineer your existing database to generate entity json files. However there is a module currently under development that may change the situation in near future: https://github.com/bastienmichaux/generator-jhipster-db-helper